# how to specify the view or controller for running javascript 'document.ready'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to run javascript like bellow when the page is loaded.

```
$ ->
  $.getJSON '/memos.json', (data) ->
    $.each( data ), (key,memo)->
      $('#memos').append( "#{memo.title} #{memo.content}<br/>")
```

but I want to run this only after 'users/show.html.erb' is loaded.
the view is like bellow

```
<div id="memos"></div>
```

I think there are two approaches to do this.
One is to specify the views loaded, and the second one is to specify the controller.

I don't think writing javascript on erb file is a good idea.
Is there any way to implement them?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the

```
$ ->
    ..
```

on the first line, will be translated to

```
$(function() {
  ...
});
```

which is basically is a shorthand for JQuery's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
});
```

which means that the script inside of this function will only be executed once the DOM is ready.

so You could save the javascript into separate file let say `js/memos/index.js` and within your view `app/views/memo/index.html.erb' you would have the`` and on the same file you can include the javascript with javascript include tag.

The javascript will only be executed once DOM is ready, meaning at that point you will already have the div.

More info on JQuery's `ready` http://api.jquery.com/ready/